# Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) Repository does not have a Release file after installing Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

After installing docker I could not use sudo apt-get update. I would get the following error:

> 404  Not Found [IP: 11.111.11.11 11] Reading package lists... Done E:
>   The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release'
>   does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't
>   be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.

I am new to Linux so sorry if I am a bit noobish. I have tried uninstalling docker and the issue still persists. I also tried a lot of solutions I found online and could not find any success. Please let me know if you need anymore information.